# Partial boost library

Tags: c++, boost

I am interested in small parts of [Boost](http://www.boost.org) library and I don't want to have the whole library on my configuration management (ex. SVN). So I was thinking about stripping required libraries from the big library.

I tried to extract [circular_buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html), but I found that it depends on many other modules/files. Each Boost library is really-dependent-on-other-boost-libraries.

Did any one succeeded to extract a single-boost library outside the big library?

Answer (score 3):

See the [BCP tool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) which does exactly that.